# I get empty image when saving canvas2html image in mysql using php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I can successfully create canvas2html image and tried to save it on my computer. But I was trying to insert it in MySQL database using PHP. I found this code [here](http://www.kubilayerdogan.net/html2canvas-take-screenshot-of-web-page-and-save-it-to-server-javascript-and-php/).

It saved something in my database, but when I try to retrieve it I get empty or image that cannot be shown, so to understand what is going on.

I changed the input type from hidden to text, and I found that the value is not changing per each time I try to generate it (i made changes in the canvas2html div so it suppose to show different value).
Moreover, the command: echo '';
is showing nothing, which confirm that it actually save nothing or empty image.

I posted the code here as well:

```js
function capture() {
    $('#target').html2canvas({
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            //Set hidden field's value to image data (base-64 string)
            $('#img_val').val(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
            //Submit the form manually
            document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<div id="target">
<!-- Render your page inside of this div. -->
</div>

<input type="submit" value="Take Screenshot Of Div" onclick="capture();" />
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="save.php" id="myForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="img_val" id="img_val" value="" />
</form>
<!-- PHP part -->
<? PHP
//I  have set the connection and everything is working fine
//Show the image
echo '<img src="'.$_POST['img_val'].'" />';
 
//Get the base-64 string from data
$filteredData=substr($_POST['img_val'], strpos($_POST['img_val'], ",")+1);
 
//Decode the string
$unencodedData=base64_decode($filteredData);
 
//Save the image
$image= file_put_contents('img.png', $unencodedData);

$sqlinsert= "INSERT INTO EntranceCards (InvitorMobile, EventID, GuestName, guestpercard, SN, QRIMAGE) VALUE('$Mobile','$Eid','$GN','$GPC','$SN', $image)";

if(mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlinsert))
            {
              echo 'insertion done';           
            }
            
        if(!mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlinsert)){ 
die ('error inserting');
?>
```